# Encoding png images in base64 using Buffer with React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, base64, buffer

I am trying to encode my png image in base64 using buffer. It is happening in React useEffect and in the end want to upload to arweave.

```
   const [imageBuffer, setImageBuffer] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        const loadImage = async () => {
            const response = await fetch('./assets/ohr2.png');
            const buffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
            var base64data = Buffer.from(buffer).toString('base64');
           setImageBuffer(base64data);
      }
        loadImage();
    }, [])
```

And in my on click function

```
let transaction = await arweave.createTransaction(
              { data: imageBuffer },
               arweaveKey
           );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const [imageBuffer, setImageBuffer] = useState(null);

 useEffect(() => {
    const loadImage = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(require("your_img_path"));
        const arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
        const buffer = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer);
        setImageBuffer(buffer);
    }
    loadImage();
}, []);
```